# Execute asyncio task as soon as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, event-loop

I would like to know how can I execute the tasks group 'tg_fast' immediately, and after, continue the tasks group 'tg_main'(or start again if not possible to continue).
In use asyncio.gather(), the result is like TaskGroup.

```
import asyncio


async def another_coro(i):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)


async def coro(i):
    if i == 1:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg_fast:
            tg_fast.create_task(another_coro(i * 10))
            tg_fast.create_task(another_coro(i * 100))
        # await asyncio.gather(*[another_coro(i * 10), another_coro(i * 100)])
    else:
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg_main:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            tg_main.create_task(coro(i))


asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

printing is 0 => 2 => 10 => 100

But I would a method to get: 0 => 10 => 100 => ... OR 0 => 100 => 10 => ...

The goal being to initiate 10 and 100 after 0 and before 2.

Thanks you very much for your help.

Edit:
I want to call 'another_coro' simultaneously. Not wait for one and start the second one after.
And I don't need to finish them, I can execute both until await 'asyncio.sleep(.1') and continue the event loop.

Comment: Await the coroutine directly and don't convert it to a task.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I can't, because I want to call simultaneous another_coro. Not await one and start the second after

Comment: I don't think Python gives you the ability to control the order that the event loop schedules tasks. Maybe a producer-consumer pattern using a [Priority Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#priority-queue) to decide the order in which the consumer starts the work would work?

Comment: @DzedCPT Yes, I have developed a similar example with asyncio.PriorityQueue and it can work. But I wanted to know if there is an easier way because it makes my code more complex. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: Python will execute the tasks in the order that they are created. I don't think this is part of the language spec but it is how it's currently implemented. So you could create another async task group called `tg_slow` in the `else` statement which calls `tg_slow.create_task(another_coro(i))`. And this will be scheduled after the tg_fast tasks so it should execute in the order that you want.

Comment: @DzedCPT So instead of initializing all my tasks in my hand, I run one then if it doesn't meet the condition, I run the next one? If I understand correctly what you mean.
Isn't there a way to freeze/stop/cancel tg_main to switch to tg_fast as quickly as possible?

Comment: Maybe, but not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you have to deliberately add another mechanism to prioritize tasks, and it has to be done explicitly to your other tasks in the "non priority" group.

It could be done by, for example, subclassing asyncio.TaskGroup, and add a priority mechanism to the `__aexit__` method, so that when a group is intended to be exited (and all its tasks intended to be awaited), it could check in a central registry for all your instances of your specialized TaskGroup if there is a TaskGroup with greater priority running, and then wait until that one exits  -

That would work without needing to change any code in your tasks -just how you instantiate your groups - but on the other hand, if would not prevent the non-prioritized tasks from step and run parts in any other point inthe code they await (or otherwise yield to the asyncio loop).

Another approach, for which I wrote the snippet bellow, requires you to *change* the tasks that are to have lower priority at points, and call a specialized `sleep` in them (it can be called with "0" delay, just as `asyncio.sleep`) .  The points where these calls are placed become explicit points where your tasks will yield priority to the tasks that should run first.

This allows greater flexibility, is more explicit, and is guaranteed to pause your lower priority work - the downside being you have to explicitly add the "checkpoints" in your code.

Perceive that this works by the modified `.sleep`  method simply not returning while there is any other higher priority task running.

```
import asyncio
from heapq import  heappush, heapify

granularity = 0.01


class PriorityGroups:

    def __init__(self):
        self.priority_queue = []
        self.counter = 0

    async def sleep(self, delay, priority=10):
        counter = self.counter
        self.counter += 1
        steps = delay / granularity
        step_delay = delay / steps
        step = 0
        heappush(self.priority_queue, (priority, counter))
        try:
            while step < steps or (self.priority_queue and self.priority_queue[0][0] < priority):
                await asyncio.sleep(step_delay)
                step += 1
        finally:
            self.priority_queue.remove((priority, counter))
            heapify(self.priority_queue)


priority_group = PriorityGroups()



async def another_coro(i, priority=1):
    await priority_group.sleep(.1, priority)
    print(i)


async def coro(i):
    if i == 1:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg_fast:
            tg_fast.create_task(another_coro(i * 10))
            tg_fast.create_task(another_coro(i * 100))

        # await asyncio.gather(*[another_coro(i * 10), another_coro(i * 100)])
    else:
        await priority_group.sleep(.1)
        print(i)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg_main:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            tg_main.create_task(coro(i))


asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

So - just place calls for the same instance of `PriorityGroups.sleep`, optionally passing a lower number for the priority (==more prioritary), for things that should run first. Having the control placed in an instance of PriorityGroups even means you can have parallel nested groups of tasks and priority tasks, and one group won't interfere with the others.

Comment: A huge thank you for your answer and the development of this one! Excellent work, thank you very much!

Comment: I've checked some of the code - ultimately, there could be a custom EventLoop that would take in account a "priority" parameter, which could be in each task context. - That is even a package-worth thing. As, on my side, I have no real need for this for now, it is little probable I'd do such a thing - but it would be fun.

Comment: Another question made me realize that if one needs a set of co-routines to get accomplished before others, while pausing completly those others, a simple way may be to start another asyncio loop in another thread, and wat synchronously on that thread -  check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347457/python-asyncio-possible-to-run-a-secondary-event-loop/75365776#75365776