# Python asyncio, possible to run a secondary event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Is there a way to create a secondary asyncio loop(or prioritize an await) that when awaited does not pass control back to the main event loop buts awaits for those 'sub' functions? IE

```
import asyncio
async def priority1():
    print("p1 before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(11)
    print("p1 after sleep")

async def priority2():
    print("p2 before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(11)
    print("p2 after sleep")

async def foo():
    while True:
        print("foo before sleep")
        #do not pass control back to main event loop here but run these 2 async 
        await asyncio.gather(priority1(),priority2())
        print("foo after sleep")

async def bar():
    while True:
        print("bar before sleep")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("bar after sleep")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(),bar())


asyncio.run(main())
```

I would like foo to wait for priority1/2 to finish before passing control back to the main event loop.

Right now it would go:

```
foo before sleep
bar before sleep
p1 before sleep
p2 before sleep
bar after sleep
```

I would like to see:

```
foo before sleep
bar before sleep
p1 before sleep
p2 before sleep
p1 after sleep
p2 after sleep
bar after sleep
```

Is this possible?
thanks

Comment: Not sure, if it is sensible to run _two_ event loops in the same thread. It seems to me as though you might want to just run `priority1` and `priority2` in a separate thread. Or do you actually want a means of synchronization, so as to actually wait for them to finish before _some other coroutine_ does its thing? Because I see no real point in blocking the _entire_ event loop just because you want _some_ functions to be executed sequentially. I think you need to elaborate a bit because this smells like an [**XY Problem**](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You are correct, when foo and bar find the correct information, I need priority1/2 to run async with top priority IE foo and bar do not need to run and possibly use cpu(slowing the execution of p1/2) while priority1/2 are running however p1/2 need to run async. Does this clear it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to run two event loops on the same thread. The code in asyncio and specs even look like they were thought in a way to permit that - but afterwards the API bent in a way it is no longer possible (for example, the explicit `loop` parameter for several of the relevant calls has been deprecated and removed)

In the same line, there is no way to prioritize a subset of tasks in the running loop. I answered a question on this line a couple weeks ago, and managed to get to a synchronization primitive to be used in place of `asyncio.sleep` which could take priority into account - but it requires all participating tasks to call it, so it would not be much different of a lock or something (I will link to it bellow - the idea is: your code call `await custom.sleep()` at certain points: it will only return when there are no other higher-prioritized tasks also calling that custom.sleep()  ) -check it here: [Execute asyncio task as soon as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209793/execute-asyncio-task-as-soon-as-possible/75212513#75212513)

When wrtting that code, I realized that *it is possible* to write an event loop which could take into account a "priority" attribute on tasks. But having a production-grade for this requires some non-hobby work: by using that loop, you could get what you are asking for, with no changes needed in the tasks code.

However, I think running a secondary loop in another thread, and then waiting synchronously on that thread to complete is a way to get your things accomplished.

```
import asyncio
import threading

def priority(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = None
        def runner(*args, **kw):
            nonlocal result
            result = asyncio.run(func(*args, **kw))
        t = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        t.start()
        # if one wants to perform limited yields to the main loop, it should be done here
        t.join()
        return result

    return wrapper


async def priority1():
    print("p1 before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(.11)
    print("p1 after sleep")

async def priority2():
    print("p2 before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(.11)
    print("p2 after sleep")

@priority
async def foo():

    print("foo before sleep")
    #do not pass control back to main event loop here but run these 2 async
    await asyncio.gather(priority1(),priority2())
    print("foo after sleep")

async def bar():
    print("bar before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(.05)
    print("bar after sleep")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(),bar())


asyncio.run(main())
```